# Is there something like javascript 'confirm(msg)' in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-alertdialog, confirm

I need functionality like javascript 'confirm(msg)' in Android.
Something like AlertDialog, but with possibility to return value, not callback.
Is there any way to implement this?

UPDATE
functionality like this is not suitable for my problem:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        method1();
    });
builder.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        method2();
    });
```

I need something like this:

```
if (confirmDialog.askConfirm()) {
    method1();
} else {
    method2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is what you're looking for:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: I know it well, but it is not that I need. I've updated my question.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @GhostCat I was planning on doing it that way but I can't do that with the amount of reputation I have. If I were able to do so it would be damn difficult to find the box I could press to do it that way. But again thanks for the tip

Comment: Well, you just made some progress on that perspective. Beyond that - leave out such things as "thank you", "youre welcome" and so on. For this answer, I suggest to *summarize* that page - no need to have screenshots or show pictures.

Comment: @GhostCat I look for answers all the time on this website and I have just been picking things up about how to write or answer things on this site. I saw people saying things like: "You're welcome" so I thought it was a normal thing to do. Like a baby kid learning the words and behaviours from their parents.

Comment: Thing is: such things are fine in comments (although we usually start cleaning up and delete things at some point). But keep in mind: this is a intended as Question / Answer site. The questions and answers should stand for themselves, sometimes for many many readers over time. So focus on the question, or the answer. And use comments for the rest (what is if course not easy until you get to 50 rep and "comment level")

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved my problem this way:

```
public class JSStyleConfirmDialog {
    private volatile boolean interrupted = false;
    private volatile boolean result;
    private volatile boolean resultObtained = false;

    public static final int YES = 1;
    public static final int NO = 0;
    public static final int ERROR = -1;

    public int askConfirm(final ClientActivity activity, final String msg) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!resultObtained) {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    interrupted = true;
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                builder.setMessage(msg);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        result = true;
                        resultObtained = true;
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        result = false;
                        resultObtained = true;
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return ERROR;
        }

        if (interrupted) {
            return ERROR;
        }

        return result?YES:NO;
    }
}
```

This must be called from non-ui thread:

```
int result = new JSStyleConfirmDialog().askConfirm(activity, msg);
```